# capybara how to test multiple links with href pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, capybara

Given I have a page with a 10 users listing,
How can I test that I have 10 user show links ?

I've tried this :

```
   Then /^I should see a list of (\d+) users$/ do |num|
     page.should have_selector('a', {:href=>"users/*", :count => num})
   end
```

And this :

```
   Then /^I should see a list of (\d+) users$/ do |num|
     page.should have_selector('a', {:href=>/users\/\d+/, :count => num})
   end
```

But both return expected css "a" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

If I omit the :count parameter, however, the test always passes whatever I have (even faulty pattern) in the :href param.

Comment: Not a solution, but wouldn't it be easier to add a "user" class to your links, rather than to bother with a regex?

Comment: This could be a solution, but I wanted not to rely on markup. The user_path is the only think I'm sure that won't change on my page.

Answer (score 6):

I would use an xpath with the `contains` function for this:

```
page.should have_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'users')]"), :count => num)
```

Should match `num` occurrences of any `a` element with an `href` attribute containing the text 'users'.